# environment variable not working

Tags: command-line, bash, python, environment-variables, django

i am doing a python-django project, And what i want to do is, i want to set

variables like password,db_name etc as an environment variable. And i want

to access it as os.environ["db_name"]

i tried like this

inside /home/thameem/Django_projects/lotus/env_var

```
export db_name="thameem"
```

inside /etc/environment file

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"


PATH="$PATH:/home/thameem/Django_projects/lotus/env_var"
```

and in terminal i tried :

```
echo $db_name
```

but it does not shows the value of db_name

if the question is not correct, somebody please correct the question

i checked this one :: [How do I add environment variables?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables)

Comment: Please use the community wiki page [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) as the principle reference on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the assignments in a separate `env_var` file, you would need to *source* it from one of your shell's startup files, rather than adding it to your `PATH`

For example, you could add something like

```
if [ -r "$HOME/Django_projects/lotus/env_var" ]; then
  . "$HOME/Django_projects/lotus/env_var"
fi
```

to the bottom of your `~/.profile`

I don't recommend adding it to a system-wide file such as `/etc/profile` since the file is in your home directory.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i copied your code inside the .profile file and open a new terminal and i entered the echo $db_name. But it not shows the value of db_name. it shows blank.

Comment: It will be set next time you log in - or you can open a new login shell in your current session either explicitly (using `bash -l`) or implicitly  (e.g. `su - thameem`)