# Setting path permanently for openmpi in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

Every new instance of terminal forces me to export openmpi path before using it. I tried setting the path permanently using

```
echo export PATH="$PATH:/home/$USER/.openmpi/bin" >> /home/$USER/.bashrc


echo export 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/$USER/.openmpi/lib/">> home/$USER/.bashrc
```

However, this is not working.
Please suggest a solution.

Thank you

Comment: If you want to have exactly this string `export PATH="$PATH:/home/$USER/.openmpi/bin"` in `~/.bashrc` you must put single quotes into the command: `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/home/$USER/.openmpi/bin"' >> /home/$USER/.bashrc`. In other case variables will be substituted by their values.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/home/$USER/.openmpi/bin"' | tee -a /home/$USER/.bashrc
```

and

```
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/$USER/.openmpi/lib/"' | tee -a /home/$USER/.bashrc
```

Comment: I have tried your solution plus
http://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168340/where-is-ld-library-path-how-do-i-set-the-ld-library-path-env-variable
Wonder what the problem is. Please comment.