# Why I can't start android emulator?

Tags: android, sdk

Why I can't start android emulator?
There is error message like this,

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Sen'
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator": error=13, Permission denied
```

error message of android emulator
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are running a program from `/opt` folder.
You need  to run it with `sudo`

or you could move your sdk to your home folder where you have read/write access.

Third way is to set `chmod -R 775 /opt/android-sdk-linux` .
I suggest the second method.

Comment: i'll try it, tyvm Mr Suraj

Comment: it work, but now i have this error

Comment: Starting emulator for AVD 'Sentosa34'
ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them you will have to do at least one of the following:
- Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
- Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.

Comment: are you using a 32 bit or 64 bit machine?

Comment: 32bit machine Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop LTS

Comment: I guess you will have to do what the warning is telling you.. try setting ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to true..

Comment: I havent used 32 bit version of android studio/sdk

Comment: how can i do that? setting ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to true? is environment .profile?

Comment: same way you set ANDROID_HOME.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables