# How to set a global persistent variable?

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables

I'm creating a bashscript to setup a small application I'm writing. Part of that setup requires setting an environment variable so that other processes may reference it.

My simple shell script test looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

export FOO=abc
```

I understand why `FOO` will not be visible after the script is executed, if done like so:

```
$ sh script.sh
```

and why this will make it visible:

```
$ source script.sh
```

so that's a workaround, but I'm wondering how common install scripts do this - for example, I'm pretty sure installers like mysql etc do set global environment variables.

What is the right way to do this? I guess I can ask my users to install by running:

```
$ source script.sh
```

but not sure if there is a better way.

Thanks

Comment: Possible solutions:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines to your script. Your script should have `root` access.

```
echo 'export FOO=abc' > /etc/profile.d/foo.sh
```

Next restart it will be available.